# Issue with opening csv file

Tags: php, file-upload, csv

Hey guys I have the following:

```
session_start();
$seterror = 0;

function returnBack(){

    header("Location:../memberinterface.php?getmsg=15");
    exit;

}
function returnBackfile(){

    header("Location:../memberinterface.php?getmsg=16");
    exit;
}
if (!empty($_FILES['csvfile']['error'] ) )
    {

        $seterror = 1;
        returnBack();

    } 
    if (empty($_POST['firstname'])){

        $seterror =1;
        returnBack();
    }
    if (empty($_POST['lastname'])){
        $seterrro =1;

        returnBack();
    }
    if (empty($_POST['email'])){
        $seterror =1;

        returnBack();
    }
    if ($seterror !== 1){

    $file = $_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name']; 

    $handle = fopen($file , "r");

    $fileop = fgetcsv($handle,0,"\t");
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($fileop); var_dump($_POST); echo '</pre>';
    exit;
    $fileop=array_map("strtoupper",array_map("trim",$fileop));

    $firstname_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST["firstname"]),$fileop);
    if ($firstname_index===false){
        returnBack();
    }
    $lastname_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST["lastname"]),$fileop);
    if ($lastname_index===false){

        returnBack();
    }
    $email_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST["email"]),$fileop);
    if ($email_index===false){

        returnBack();
    }
        //open file and store values
        $j = 0;
        while (($fileop=fgetcsv($handle,0,"\t")) !== false)
        {

            $fileop=array_map("trim",$fileop);
            $firstname[$j] = $fileop[$firstname_index];
            if (empty($firstname[$j])){ 

            returnBackfile();

            }

            $lastname[$j] = $fileop[$lastname_index];
                if (empty($lastname[$j])){

            returnBackfile();

            }
            $email[$j] = $fileop[$email_index];
                if (empty($email[$j])){

            returnBackfile();


            }
            $j++;
        }
        //create sessions, send back to memberinterface.php and open table to display the results to delete
        $_SESSION['CSVRfirstnames'] = $firstname;
        $_SESSION['CSVRlastnames'] = $lastname;
        $_SESSION['CSVRemails'] = $email;

        header("Location:../memberinterface.php?RemoveCSV=1");
    }
```

And the section where I echo out the columns: `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($fileop); var_dump($_POST); echo '</pre>';` - a weird thing happens.

For some CSV files I get this outprinted:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(726) "PK!|l˜l [Content_Types].xml ¢( Ì”]KÃ0†ïÿCÉ­4Ù&ˆÈº]øq©çˆÍé–&!'›Û¿÷4û@¤nzÓÐæœ÷}’4ïp¼jL¶„€ÚÙ‚õye`K§´ìmú”ß²£´Jg¡`k@6]^§k˜Q·Å‚Õ1ú;!°¬¡‘ÈK3•ŒôfÂËr.g ½Þ(`c[
6>@%&f+ú¼!"
  [1]=>
  string(71) "`e÷›ÂÖ«`Ò{£K‰T,­úæ’o8u¦¬µÇ+Â`¢Ó¡ùÙ`Û÷B[´‚l"C|–
aˆ•.Ìß›óÃ"”®ªt"
  [2]=>
  string(951) "v€£ Ö±1<¼‘Úî¸ø§bièŸ¤]_>‘cðO8®ÿˆ#Òÿ"=$IæÈ`\À3¯v#zÌ¹–Ôk”gøª}ˆƒîÑ$8”(Nß…]d´Ý¹'!QÃ>4º.ßÞ‘ÒètÃo·Ú¼S :¼EÊ×Ñ'ÿÿPK!µU0#õL_rels/.rels ¢( Œ’ÏNÃ0ÆïH¼CäûênH¡¥»LH»!TÀ$îµ£$@÷ö„‚JcÛÑöçÏ?[ÞîæiTb/NÃº(A±3b{×jx­ŸV b"giÇŽaWÝÞl_x¤”›b×û¨²‹‹º”ü#b4Oñìr¥‘0QÊahÑ“¨eÜ”å=†¿P-<ÕÁj{ª>ú<ù²·4Mox/æ}b—NŒ@ž;ËvåCf©ÏÛ¨šBËIƒóœÓÉû"cž&Ú\Oôÿ¶8q"K‰ÐHàó<ßŠs@ëë.Ÿh©ø½Î<â§„áMdøaÁÅT_ÿÿPK!Þ"
  [3]=>
  string(530) "(Ôxl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels ¢( ¼“ÏjÃ0Æïƒ½ƒÑ}q’ne”:½ŒA¯[÷&QâÐÄ6–ö'o?“Cº@É.¡ƒ$ü}?Ð§ýá§ïÄjU%)´¥«ZÛ(ø8½><ƒ Ö¶Ò³¨`@‚Cq·ÃNsüD¦õ$¢Š%†Ùï¤¤Ò`¯)qmœÔ.ôšcéuyÖ
Ê
  string(9) "Firstname"
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(8) "lastname"
  ["email"]=>
  string(5) "Email"
}
```

And other csv files I get it nicely organized:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "firstname"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "lastname"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "email"
  [3]=>
}
array(3) {
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(9) "Firstname"
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(8) "lastname"
  ["email"]=>
  string(5) "email"
}
```

Now I don't know why I am getting the weird symbols for some, and I don't want those so if you could help me that would be great!

David

Comment: Seems like an encoding problem.

Comment: May not answer your question, but there's usually a space between the colon in `header("Location:` and the file location. Unless it works for you.

Comment: Oh ya that works Fred :)

Comment: this might help.. http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/convert-smart-quotes-with-php

Comment: You either have an encoding problem or the notorious `BOM`. If incorporating `utf8_encode()` doesn't work, look into `BOM`.

Comment: Hmmm tried putting the //Úτƒ-8 encoded but no cigar

Comment: @Fred you got any other idea?

Comment: @DavidBiga Check out Notepad++ to test and encode `with` or `without` the `BOM` (byte order mark) http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ and consult http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark - that's all that comes to mind. It's been known to cause problems similar to yours.

Comment: @Fred I changed my settings in my dreamweaver to encode in BOM and without and made sure it was ut8-encode

Comment: @DavidBiga Consult also http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: @DavidBiga have you tested "both"?

Comment: Yes no goo...fred enter chat if you could

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27294/discussion-between-david-biga-and-fred)

Comment: Seems like your "others CSV files" are not CSV files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your .CSV file is saved as "comma delimited" or "tab delimited" in Excel. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Some of yours "CSV" files are not CSV files. This ackward structure you are printing is potentially the content of a `.xlsx` file or some of the many other Microsoft Office 2007 formats.

If I create a blank `.docx` or `.xlsx` file and see in the hexadecimal editor I will see something like this:

```
00000000h: 50 4B 03 04 14 00 06 00 08 00 00 00 21 00 DD FC ; PK..........!.Ýü
00000010h: 95 37 66 01 00 00 20 05 00 00 13 00 08 02 5B 43 ; •7f... .......[C
00000020h: 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 5F 54 79 70 65 73 5D 2E 78 6D ; ontent_Types].xm
00000030h: 6C 20 A2 04 02 28 A0 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; l ¢..( .........
00000040h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000050h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000060h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
```

Quite familiar, isn't it?

Those files are actually `.zip` files contenting a tree of .xml files and other resources belonging to your document.

Answer (score 0):

can you try utf8_encode() on the string?

Comment: Where would I put that?

Comment: anywhere you would want to output the string such as echo such as utf8_encode($fileop[0]);